# Canvas.js chart not updating with new data

Tags: javascript, html, graph, canvasjs, myo

I'm using CanvasJS to create a line graph based on some numbers coming in from my Myo. When new data comes in, the graph doesn't update. Since I don't populate the graph with initial data points, it stays empty forever.

My code: [Here](http://pastebin.com/Rw5tvsL5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

Lets say:
var myChart = new CanvasJS.Chart(...);

Then to update chart data use:
myChart.options.data[0].dataPoints = YOUR_DATA_ARRAY;
myChart.render();

Worked for me, as I didn't find any 'update' method in documentation.